# Copying bytes into a double array

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to copy a stream of bytes into a double array.  The bytes won't necessarily represent double values, the double array is just being used as a storage mechanism (I realize this is crazy, but it is a current restriction on our framework and we have a deadline).  However I have found that in some circumstances when copying the double array back into a byte array the data has changed.

I have narrowed it down to the following test case failing

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var bytes = new byte[]
            {
                24,
                108,
                6,
                14,
                7,
                91,
                242,
                255
            };

        double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 0);

        var returnedBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);

        for (int i = 0; i < returnedBytes.Count(); i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(bytes[i], returnedBytes[i]);
        }
    }
```

I realize now that there is some underlying framework function stopping me taking this approach.  However out of interest can anyone explain why the above test case is failing?

Comment: How do you know which endianness your source (and your own processor) are using?

Comment: Does that matter in this case?  The above test case is entirely in memory, on the same processor and within the .Net framework.

Answer (score 3):

Because the value you supplied is not a valid encoding of a IEE754 double--at least on a little-endian architecture, which is probably what you have. The `double` you produce above is `NaN`, which is an entire range of binary values that don't compute to a in-range double. It's not surprising that the framework returns a 'standard' or at least mutated `NaN`.

If you reverse the order of the 32-bit words to:

```
7, 91, 242, 255, 24, 108, 6, 14
```

You may end up with 4.20332332290442E-241.

Alternatively, reversing the order of the bytes *within* the 32-bit words:

```
14, 6, 108, 24, 255, 242, 91, 7
```

Yields 3.22903984511934E-273

Finally, reversing the entire list (little-ending 64-bit register)

```
255, 242, 91, 7, 14, 6, 108, 24
```

Yields 4.91380011890093E-191

So, yes, you need to figure out what the source encoding is, and what your own is. Note this may vary whether you are running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

Comment: That does look like a valid number reversed, however the byte array came out of a compression algorithm so I didn't expect the number to make any sense.  I was just trying to use the double array as a storage mechanism, however this is clearly a bad idea :)

Comment: @mattythomas2000 Why not just use a `byte[]`? What's the point of bunching the bytes into 8-byte blocks?

Comment: Yes I agree, it seems crazy.  We have a framework that can handle double[] but can't handle byte[] so I thought I'd try and be clever.  However I think the solution is to make the framework handle byte[].  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`BitConverter` does not screw around with the bits at all -- it never even checks them, so there is no standard `NaN` being mapped when it sees a nonsensical value. It is however possible the JIT is generating code which results in the CPU screwing with your bits.

If it is putting `double` in 80-bit registers, there are some hidden conversions going on. In pseudo-C:

```
float80 d = *(float64*)bytes;
*(float64*)bytes = d;
```

In the transition between 80-bit register and 64-bit storage, the CPU would mangle your value.